# Android NDK -Linker errors to shared libraries.

Tags: c++, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I'm trying to figure out why I keep getting undefined references to functions that are declared in shared libraries that come with android.

My application.mk and root android.mk

```
APP_MODULES    :=   adhoc
APP_STL := gnustl_shared
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=clang3.1
APP_OPTIM    := debug

CUR_PATH := $(call my-dir)
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -std-c++11 -Wwrite-strings

include   $(CUR_PATH)/native/adhoc/Android.mk
```

adhoc Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
updater_src_files := \
  install.cpp\
    sha1.cpp\
  addhoc_lib.cpp 


include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(updater_src_files)

inc_path = $(NDK_ROOT)/../AndroidSource/system/core/include \
$(NDK_ROOT)/../AndroidSource/hardware/libhardware_legacy/include

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(inc_path)

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DINTERNAL_SHA1 -DCONFIG_CRYPTO_INTERNAL -DCONFIG_NO_T_PRF -DCONFIG_NO_TLS_PRF -std=c++11 -Wc++11-extensions -Wno-deprecated-writable-strings

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libedify

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libcutils\
              libhardware_legacy\
              libc\
              libnetutils\
              libsysutils

LOCAL_MODULE := adhoc

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-add-path, $(LOCAL_PATH))
$(call import-module, edify)
```

and adhoc/edify/android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

edify_src_files := \
    lexer.l \
    parser.y \
    expr.c

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(edify_src_files)

LOCAL_CFLAGS := $(edify_cflags)
LOCAL_MODULE := edify

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

I get output from ndk-build -B V=1 like:

```
SharedLibrary  : libadhoc.so
/home/corey/Android_Dev/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/llvm-3.1/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/clang++ -Wl,-soname,libadhoc.so -shared --sysroot=/home/corey/Android_Dev/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-14/arch-arm ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/adhoc/install.o ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/adhoc/sha1.o ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/adhoc/addhoc_lib.o ./obj/local/armeabi/libedify.a ./obj/local/armeabi/libgnustl_shared.so -gcc-toolchain /home/corey/Android_Dev/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86 -no-canonical-prefixes -target armv5te-none-linux-androideabi  -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now /home/corey/Android_Dev/android-ndk-r8d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/libsupc++.a -lc -lm -o ./obj/local/armeabi/libadhoc.so

/home/corey/Android_Dev/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/adhoc/install.o: in function GetPropFn(char const*, State*, int, Expr**):jni/native/adhoc/install.cpp:463: error: undefined reference to 'property_get'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C++ code, then add C PLUS PLUS flag.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus 
extern "C" {
#endif


#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Also take a look at the following post.
[android ndk undefined reference to a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080345/android-ndk-undefined-reference-to-a-method)

Comment: Well I got it to work by copying the libraries off my phone and giving the build system a path to them.  I already had the header files wrapped with extern "C".